# Unable to install nltk in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, nltk

After activating the virtual environment, when I try:

```
$ sudo pip install -U nltk
```

it shows this message:

> Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Why isn't it downloading those packages?
Should I use --no-site-packages while activating?

Comment: `Requirement already up-to-date:`... It's **already installed**

Comment: Though, I do not think you've activated the virtualenv because it's running pip from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` (and you should not need to use sudo for virtualenvs)

Comment: @cricket_007 I had activated the virtualenv but was using sudo as also poined by Denilson Sá Maia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wait, if you are inside the virtual environment, you shouldn't use `sudo`.

In fact, using `sudo` will spawn a new shell that may have different variables, and thus this sudo-shell will be outside the virtual environment. (Note: this paragraph is speculation; I have not tested it.)

Try again without `sudo`.